# How to quickly initialise an associative table in Lua?

Tags: lua, initialization, lua-table

In Lua, you can create a table the following way :

```
local t = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
```

However, I want to create an associative table, I have to do it the following way :

```
local t = {}
t['foo'] = 1
t['bar'] = 2
```

The following gives an error :

```
local t = { 'foo' = 1, 'bar' = 2 }
```

Is there a way to do it similarly to my first code snippet ?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The correct way to write this is either

```
local t = { foo = 1, bar = 2}
```

Or, if the keys in your table are not legal identifiers:

```
local t = { ["one key"] = 1, ["another key"] = 2}
```

Comment: FYI, there's a similar answer here, that contains more of an explanation, and that I found easier to understand: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16288476/5505583

Answer (score 13):

i belive it works a bit better and understandable if you look at it like this

```
local tablename = {["key"]="value",
                   ["key1"]="value",
                   ...}
```

finding a result with : **tablename.key=value**

> > Tables as dictionaries
>
> Tables can also be used to store information which is not indexed
> numerically, or sequentially, as with arrays. These storage types are
> sometimes called dictionaries, associative arrays, hashes, or mapping
> types. We'll use the term dictionary where an element pair has a key
> and a value. The key is used to set and retrieve a value associated
> with it. Note that just like arrays we can use the table[key] = value
> format to insert elements into the table. A key need not be a number,
> it can be a string, or for that matter, nearly any other Lua object
> (except for nil or 0/0). Let's construct a table with some key-value
> pairs in it:
>
> ```lua
> > t = { apple="green", orange="orange", banana="yellow" }
> > for k,v in pairs(t) do print(k,v) end
> apple   green
> orange  orange
> banana  yellow
> ```

from : http://lua-users.org/wiki/TablesTutorial

Answer (score 2):

To initialize associative array which has string keys matched by string values, you should use

```
local petFamilies = {["Bat"]="Cunning",["Bear"]="Tenacity"};
```

but **not**

```
local petFamilies = {["Bat"]=["Cunning"],["Bear"]=["Tenacity"]};
```