# Lua `local a = {b=func1}`

Tags: lua, local-functions

I am new to lua and encountered the following piece of code

```
    function X()
        local function Y() ... end
        local var1 = {var2=Y}
        ...
        return blah
    end
```

What does `local var1 = {var2=Y}` do/mean here?

Thanks!

Comment: nothing because nothing is returned

Comment: @MikeV. I understand the confusion. Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Jumped the gun on this one. Seems like it simply declares an associative array (`table`) with key as "var2" and value as Y. Equivalent to the following:

```
local function Y() ... end
local var1 = {}
var1['var2'] = Y
```

More details here: [How to quickly initialise an associative table in Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513239/how-to-quickly-initialise-an-associative-table-in-lua)

Comment: Note that `Y` is a closure and will be reinstantiated every time `X` is called, so no two `var1` tables will contain the same instance of `Y`.